# Can anyone confirm if this is a true released glottal stop?

Tags: phonetics

It sounds like one to me but I'm not sure regarding how it is made. I noticed that when I consciously try to close my glottis the glottal stop is much more soft while when I don't think about closing and instead think about coughing it gets much louder, as you hear in the recording. I don't know what volume we can reach with a true glottal stop but for some reason I think I'd get more noise if tightning each cord agaisnt itself instead of themselves. That by the way is what I think I'm doing.

https://vocaroo.com/i/s1dHypk1PrTn

Comment: The link is asking me to download some commercial software.

Comment: vocaroo is a fairly common sharing site. I don't know how trustworthy it is, actually, but it played the sound in the browser last time I checked years ago.

Comment: In my phone it plays in the browser without installing anything.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a speech sound, so not a glottal stop or anything like it. It sounds like what happens when you thwack your adams apple with your finger, with your glottis closed and mouth open. If you have *just* a glottal stop, there's no sound at all, so at the minimum you would need something leading into the glottal stop (then slam the vocal folds shut, no release). A "release" would be some very short vowel-like sound (turbulence from the sudden rush of air through the glottis), and would resemble whatever vowel came before it.

It is possible that such a release feature exists in some languages, because there are reports of "glottally interrupted" vowels of the type [VʔV̆], with a very short echo vowel after the glottal stop. [This article](https://journals.dartmouth.edu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Journals.woa/xmlpage/1/article/388?htmlOnce=yes) on Chuxnabán Mixe discusses this, and provides samples (in this case, the "echo" is relatively long compared to examples that I've heard elsewhere).

Comment: It is. Did you try using another browser?

Comment: @user6726, I can't cite the page, but Ladefoged et al (2010) says a released glottal stop is like a plosive. Also, sound chains that suposedly have a glottal stop in them, like those in Hawaiian, sometimes have that small plosive sound that is much similar to mine but softer.